# Need help in filtering top 3 counts from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, analytics

Hi I am looking to get the top 3 string counts under the data frame heads with time lines with below code able to extract the counts of all strings but how can I apply a filter of top3 or 5 to get only those.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
table1 = pd.crosstab([df['name'], df['city']], df['Date'].dt.to_period('q'))
table.columns = [table.columns.year, table.columns.strftime('q')]

print(table1)

#Data Look like below

name    age  city        Date                  country   hight  MessageList  gender
Tom     10   NewYork       1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      X List      Male
Mark     5   London        5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Pam      7   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      Y List      Female
Tom     18   California    4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  US        163      Y List      Male
Lena    23   NewYork     12/12/2020 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     17   Colombo     11/12/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      X List      Male
Lena    23   Paris         8/1/2020 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     51   Colombo       7/1/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Z List      Male
Mark     5   Paris         5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  Japan     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  France    163      Z List      Male
Tom     10   NewYork       1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      X List      Male
Mark     5   London        5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Pam      7   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      Y List      Female
Tom     18   California    4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  US        163      Y List      Male
Lena    23   NewYork     12/12/2020 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     17   Colombo     11/12/2020 08:35:58Z  India     NaN      X List      Male
Lena    23   Paris         8/1/2020 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     51   Colombo       7/1/2020 08:35:58Z  India     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Z List      Male
Mark     5   Paris         5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  Japan     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  France    163      Z List      Male
Tom     10   NewYork       1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      X List      Male
Mark     5   London        5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Pam      7   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      Y List      Female
Tom     18   California    4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  US        163      Y List      Male
Lena    23   NewYork     12/12/2020 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     17   Colombo     11/12/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      X List      Male
Lena    23   Paris         8/1/2020 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     51   Colombo       7/1/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Z List      Male
Mark     5   Paris         5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  Japan     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Tom     18   California    4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  US        163      Y List      Male
Lena    23   NewYork     12/12/2020 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     17   Colombo     11/12/2020 08:35:58Z  India     NaN      X List      Male
Lena    23   Paris         8/1/2020 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     51   Colombo       7/1/2020 08:35:58Z  India     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Z List      Male
Mark     5   Paris         5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  Japan     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  France    163      Z List      Male
Tom     10   NewYork       1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      X List      Male
Mark     5   London        5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Pam      7   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      Y List      Female
Tom     18   California    4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  US        163      Y List      Male
Lena    23   NewYork     12/12/2020 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     17   Colombo     11/12/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      X List      Male
Lena    23   Paris         8/1/2020 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     51   Colombo       7/1/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Z List      Male
Mark     5   Paris         5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  Japan     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male

#Output expected 
Quarter        Q1     Q2    Q3    Q4    Total
city    US     12     8     24    11     55
        Japan  6      7     5     3      21
        Italy  8      3     2     5      18
```

How can I keep a filter on both rows and columns like pivoting in excel please help

Comment: Is your expected output is from the given sample dataframe?

Comment: Also your question is little confusing as you said that 'with below code able to extract the counts of all strings' but I don't see 'name' column in your expected output

Comment: My data is different it is just a representation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the answer of @Henrik Bo, following your way with crosstab:

```
table1 = pd.crosstab([ df['city']], df['Date'].dt.to_period('q'))
table1["total"] = table1.sum(axis=1)
table1.sort_values(by="total",ascending=False)[:3]
```

```
Date     2020Q3  2020Q4  2021Q1  2021Q2  total
city                                          
Paris         5       0       5       8     18
London        0       0       9       4     13
Colombo       5       5       0       0     10
```

When you are not interested in quarter period:

```
table2 = pd.crosstab([ df['city']],  df['Date'].dt.quarter.apply(lambda x: "Q" + str(x)))
table2["total"] = table2.sum(axis=1)
table2.sort_values(by="total",ascending=False)[:3]
```

```
Date     Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  total
city                          
Paris     5   8   5   0     18
London    9   4   0   0     13
Colombo   0   0   5   5     10
```

Comment: I have 30 to 40 key values under each column .... any suggestion on how can I filter top 5 and the ones I want

Answer (score 3):

I would to the following. Create a quarter column:

```
df["quarter"] = df["Date"].dt.to_period("q")
```

Then pivot the data frame, remove the column sum, sort the row sum and return the first 3 rows:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index="city",
    columns="quarter",
    values="name",
    aggfunc="count",
    fill_value=0,
    margins=True,
)[:-1].sort_values(by="All", ascending=False)[:3]
```

Output:

```
quarter  2020Q3  2020Q4  2021Q1  2021Q2  All
city                                        
Paris         5       0       5       8   18
London        0       0       9       4   13
Colombo       5       5       0       0   10
```

Comment: I am getting count decimal values 8.0, 432.0 etc how can I suppress decimals

Comment: Hmm. you shouldn't. I can not reproduce it with your data. There are no NA's and the count will return an Int.  Do you have formating in your DF output? Try to add ".astype("int")" to the pivot.